# Paws::S3::ListObjectVersions - Call returning empty versions array

Tags: amazon-web-services, perl, amazon-s3

I'm trying to get the list of versionIds for an S3 object using `Paws::S3::ListObjectVersions`.

Sample code:

```
use Paws;
use Data::Dumper;

my $bucket = '<bucket>';
my $s3 = Paws->service('S3', region => '<region>');

my $s3_object_list = $s3->ListObjects(Bucket => $bucket);

foreach my $s3_object (@{$s3_object_list->Contents}){
    print($s3_object->Key."\n");
    $s3_object_versions = $s3->ListObjectVersions(Bucket => $bucket, Prefix => $s3_object->Key);
    print Dumper($s3_object_versions);
    foreach my $s3_object_version (@{$s3_object_versions->Versions}){
        print($s3_object_version."\n");
    };
}
```

This kind of works, but it returns an empty list of versions:

```
$VAR1 = bless( {
                 'CommonPrefixes' => [],
                 'Versions' => [],
                 '_request_id' => '1234567890ABCDEF',
                 'MaxKeys' => '1000',
                 'Prefix' => '<prefix>',
                 'IsTruncated' => 0,
                 'DeleteMarkers' => [],
                 'Name' => '<bucket>'
               }, 'Paws::S3::ListObjectVersionsOutput' );
```

When doing the same with Powershell, I get this:

```
PS > (Get-S3Version -BucketName <bucket> -Prefix <prefix>).Versions

BucketName         Key              IsLatest VersionId                        LastModified          Size   StorageClass
----------         ---              -------- ---------                        ------------          ----   ------------
<bucket>           <prefix>         True     llmRo1gSe4.3ByyXurXodl_wpKlecABw 8/16/2019 10:25:43 AM 198702 STANDARD
<bucket>           <prefix>         False    ZxJzCX5kTHH3MMh.7ZL2E3Tkz.pQOCYw 8/16/2019 10:18:08 AM 198702 STANDARD
```

Is there something I'm missing when using Paws?

I use Paws under Windows Server 2012R2 with Strawberry Perl 5.30 32bit.

Comment: I tried this on Ubuntu 19.04, `Paws` version 0.41. I can confirm that the versions object is empty here too. But I get a warning from the script: `Paws::S3 is not stable / supported / entirely developed`. I will look further into this to see if I can find out what the problem is

Comment: Think I found the issue. I have submitted [a pull request](https://github.com/pplu/aws-sdk-perl/pull/340). Let me know if this fixes your issue too!

Comment: @HåkonHægland Thank you for looking into this, I hope the fix can be released soon!